# Google analytics tracking code

Tags: google-analytics

MY google analytics tracking info shows

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-107xxx48-13', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

but the code im the site html shows

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-107xxx48-29'],['_trackPageview']);
            _gaq.push(
    ['panel._setAccount', 'UA-107xxx48-13'],
    ['panel._trackPageview']
);
```

Does difference between the 'ga send' in the code and the 'gaq.push' on the site matter?

Comment: We need more information. Why do you have two different sets of code? Where do you see the first snippet? Where is the second snippet located?

Comment: The first set is what shows in analytics when i click on tracking info. The 2nd code is what i actually have in as the tracking code on my website.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your website is using an older version of the Google Analytics code. The GA website is showing you the new code. I can't tell you if you are missing out on any specific features, but if you want to make sure you are getting the most of what GA has to offer you should update your code to use the latest code.

But,  as I am sure you've noticed, your older code works just fine. So if you're satisfied with the reporting GA is currently doing then you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Also, how do I track the same event on different sub-domains? For example, if the main site is sellout.com and a customer has to select his country site from there(sellout.com/en_US, sellout.com/en_GB,sellout.com/fr_FR) how do I track the sign up button clicks separately for each sub domain? I've created different properties with different tracking ids for each country site in google analytics. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, theoretically there's no difference; your're looking at two different styles of Analytics code. It could be you have another issue though.

Without more information it's difficult to say, but it seems the code on your website is the old Google Analytics Tracking Code.

The code you are looking at in Google, is their new version of the tracking code - Universal Analytics. You need to update the Google Analytics tags on your website to match the first example which Google is giving you.

What have you built your site in, and how did you originally install your tracking code?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm not sure how to answer your question on what the site is built in. However, the original site has been changed and redirected to a new domain which uses the same tracking codes as the former.

Comment: Also, how do I track the same event on different sub-domains? For example, if the main site is sellout.com and a customer has to select his country site from there(sellout.com/en_US, sellout.com/en_GB,sellout.com/fr_FR) how do I track the sign up button clicks separately for each sub domain? I've created different properties with different tracking ids for each country site in google analytics. Thanks